# Move one child movieClip to another movieClip in Flash Action script 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have three movieClips (Columns) and each MovieClip contains diffrent number of child movieclips. I want to drag each child clip to another Columns.

So how can I change the child to another parent in action script 3.0

Answer (score 4):

I would removeChild from parent (column), add to stage (so its on top and you can drag it over your columns). And on release, determine over which column your mouse is, then simply addChild to that column (remove from stage first).

Comment: For non-Flex components, you can just call `newParent.addChild` without calling `oldParent.removeChild` - it'll be removed automatically. Flex wouldn't like it though

Comment: Yes that was the correct method i think, because removing from and to will affect my other events. I will check and update you if i found any difficulty. Thanks both of you

Comment: @Amarghosh  how can I detect the Column on the movement.The cols_1, cols_2... etc are the columns name. I want to know the current area.

Comment: Set `mouseEnabled = false` for the movie-clip while it is being dragged; Start listening for mouse-up events on each column when dragging starts; inside mouse-up handler, addchild the dragged clip to `this` object; Set the mouseEnabled back to true.

Comment: try using dropTarget property of three columns if these columns are movie-clips.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar one . But i followed a different plan. First I gave a base class for child objects. In the class there is a public var which will store column name. Set `mouseEnabled = false` for the column movieclip. And added drag event to the child objects. When drop the child in a column movieclip and i will check hittest. If the child hit any of teh column movieclip i will add the child object to the column movieclip and set the public var value inside the movieclip to the droped movieclips name. So that at last i could figure iut which containts which child object.